# Multiple occurences of % in patsubst

Tags: gnu-make

I try to get a list of all testable Go packages. A testable package is a directory, which contains a file starting with the name of the directory and ending with "_test.go".

I tried this:

```
packages:=$(patsubst %/%_test.go,%,$(wildcard */*_test.go))
```

But it does not work. Is it possible with GNU make anyhow?

Comment: Maybe also have a look at [wildcard-rec](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-wildcard-reclist-of-globs) in gmtt. You can't directly formulate the requirement that the filename is also the directory name, but for a preselection without having to use the shell it is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use multiple matching characters (`%`) in GNU Make.

Without more complete examples of your situation it's not possible to be sure, but isn't it good enough to use:

```
packages := $(patsubst %_test.go,%,$(notdir $(wildcard */*_test.go)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this now:

```
packages:=$(shell find * -type f -name '*_test.go' -printf '%h\n')
```